# How to stop Office Outlook 2010 from adding emails to suggested list when I send messages?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a small list of contacts in Outlook 2010 that I want to keep as a prompt when I try to type a new email. This stuff:

[image]

But every time I email someone, it automatically adds that person to that list.

How do I stop that?

Here's the version:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the [Auto-Complete List feature](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-suggested-recipients-in-the-to-cc-and-bcc-boxes-with-auto-complete-dbe46e31-c098-4881-8cf7-66b037bce23e) in Outlook client. Once you have typed a email address in the "To" field, the email address will be saved to Auto-Complete List if you enable it via File > Options > Mail > Use Auto-Complete List to suggest names when typing in the To, Cc, and Bcc lines.

If you'd like to delete one email address in Auto-Complete List, just click the X next to it, and if you'd like to empty the Auto-Complete List, please go to File > Options > Mail > Empty Auto-Complete List.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/62732a47-18f3-425b-8580-b31917bbb578/outlook-2010-creates-a-lot-of-suggested-contacts?forum=officeitproprevious

Hope this can be helpful.

Comment: Well, it helps with the naming of this feature but it doesn't help with what I want it to do. Again, I'm OK with it helping me type my email addresses that are in the contacts, but how do I make it not remember emails that I reply to? It makes no sense to remember those.

Comment: I'm afraid this is by design, you can't specify which addresses are remembered。

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm afraid too. Which is pretty stupid by the way, especially for a business email. Why would I want to put some rando email into that flyout. But oh well. Do you know if that could be done via some an extension?